# how to find month by date to fetch records for the given month

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have stored date like this format in db "2014-10-13" from this I need to show records only for the given month in Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysql [Month](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE MONTH( col_name ) = 3
```

In laravel:

```
$name = DB::table('tbl_name')->whereRaw('MONTH(col_name) = 3')->get();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'MONTH(bookingdate)' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `bookingreports` where `userid` = 77 and `MONTH(bookingdate)` = 9)

Comment: but there is a column name as bookingdate

Comment: You need to use a `whereRaw` if you want to use the SQL functions. `whereRaw('MONTH(col_name) = 3')`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MONTH('2014-10-13') = '10';
```

**larval :**

```
$results = DB::select('select * from users where MONTH('2014-10-13') = ?', array(10));
```

Comment: Could you please tell me this in laravel query

Comment: @user2983060, check now.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just assume the table names as users and assuming you are using eloquent since you have tagged it under laravel.

This is how you get the users who were created in a particular month.

**Eloquent:**

```
$month  = 12;// for december
$users = User::whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',[$month])->get();
return $users;
```

**Query Builder:**

```
$users = DB::table('users')->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',[$month])->get();
```

if you also want to get the month in the results then

**Eloquent:**

```
$users = User::select(['*',DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as month')])
                               ->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',[$month])->get();
```

**Query Builder:**

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select(['*',DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as month')])
                           ->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',[$month])->get();
```